# Как увеличить лимит сетевых соединений в ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

Как увеличить лимит сетевых соединений в ubuntu 14.04 ?

Вот такую ошибку выдает

> WARNING: Your specified
> max_parallel_sockets of 30000, but
> your system says it might only give us
> 4096.  Trying anyway

Comment: есть идеи ?

Comment: @Родион Преображенский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Можно посмотреть какие настройки использовались для c10k задачи (поддержка 10000 одновременных сетевых соединений), например, [`echo 32768 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#limits.filehandles)

Но в первую очередь нужно себя спросить, а нужно ли поддерживать такое кол-во соединений, то есть не является ли превышение лимита -- просто ошибкой программирования.

Comment: не помогло, все равно пишет
WARNING: Your specified max_parallel_sockets of 30000, but your system says it might only give us 4096.  Trying anyway

Answer (score 1):

[@Родион](/users/16548/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD) Преображен..., идеи?

Переставить систему (а может и сменить комп).

Например, у меня:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
809672
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
127286
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-40-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 13  17:53:56 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS \n \l
avp@avp-ubu1:~$
```